# How Shopify Facebook Store App Working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, shopify, facebook-apps

Recently I created a store using Shopify E-Commerce, They are offering a Facebook App. By using the Facebook App, we can create a store on our Facebook Page. I added some product through the Shopify dashboard, and it automatically comes on the Facebook Store.

Here the question is. How this kind of Apps are working?

I already developed some Facebook Tab App, which shows website data using frames. But in the case of Shopify Facebook App. It was showing the Products on the Home Page of the Facebook Page.

Is there any way to create our own Facebook Shop like Shopify?. I want to create my own.

Please help me.

Shopify Facebook App Plugin:
https://apps.shopify.com/facebook-store

Facebook Store Tab:
https://www.facebook.com/store.tab/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to create our own Facebook Shop like Shopify?

Not at the moment, no.

Facebook regularly tests new features such as this with a limited set of partners - and Shopify is one of them.
There is no way to apply.

If/when this feature will be made available for all 3rd-party apps, then they will announce it through the usual channels (FB dev blog, changelog, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since this was first asked back in 2016: Facebook is in the process of making this API public.

They call it the "[Shops API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/shops-api)" . At the time of this writing, it's in Alpha, but you can apply to get access to create your own integration.

The site says:

> Please note, this is a limited alpha so only select partners will be eligible for access to the API and we will only follow up with those selected.

I'll try to update this answer as more info becomes available. Feel free to edit my answer if you find out before I do!

Comment: I integrated my shop with Facebook now. I created a product Catalog with and connected them with Facebook Pixel and connected to my Facebook Page Store. Its okay now. Thank you.